# JacksonFactory one field - different type

Tags: android, json

im in nightmare, i can get from API, JSON that have array of objects with one field that can be float or string

so i can get in one reply objects with string or float in same field so its might looks like

```
[
    {
        (...)
        "amount": 1000

    },
    {
        (...)
        "amount": "10:1"
    },
```

]

i tried do something but with no result

```
@Key
private float amount;

@Key("amount")
private String amountStr;
```

im confused how to handle it, im using JacksonFactory, and no i cant change API

SOLVED

solved by changind float/String to Object

```
@Key
private Object amount;

public String getAmount(){
  return (String) amount;
}
```

Comment: Do you have getter and setter for amount?

Comment: i have getter  (this is missing letter that SO want me to add)